# Android - Can't find what's throwing NullPointerException at line 106

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

'm trying to find out what's throwing a `NullPointerException` in my app . Can someone help me?

the error line

```
            listener.onWeatherResponse(result);
```

The Main code:

```
public class YahooClient {


    public static List<CityResult> getCityList(String cityName) {
        List<CityResult> result = new ArrayList<CityResult>();
        HttpURLConnection yahooHttpConn = null;
        try {
            String query =makeQueryCityURL(cityName);
            Log.d("Swa", "URL [" + query + "]");
            yahooHttpConn= (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(query)).openConnection();
            yahooHttpConn.connect();
            XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(yahooHttpConn.getInputStream()));
            Log.d("Swa", "XML Parser ok");
            int event = parser.getEventType();

            CityResult cty = null;
            String tagName = null;
            String currentTag = null;

            // We start parsing the XML
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                tagName = parser.getName();

                if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                   if (tagName.equals("place")) {
                      // place Tag Found so we create a new CityResult
                      cty = new CityResult();
                       Log.d("Swa", "New City found");
                   }
                    currentTag = tagName;
                    Log.d("Swa", "Tag ["+tagName+"]");
                }
                else if (event == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    // We found some text. let's see the tagName to know the tag related to the text
                    if ("woeid".equals(currentTag))
                        cty.setWoeid(parser.getText());
                    else if ("name".equals(currentTag))
                        cty.setCityName(parser.getText());
                    else if ("country".equals(currentTag))
                        cty.setCountry(parser.getText());

                    // We don't want to analyze other tag at the moment
                }
                else if (event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if ("place".equals(tagName))
                        result.add(cty);
                }

                event = parser.next();
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
             Log.e("Error in getCityList", t.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            try {
              yahooHttpConn.disconnect();
            }
            catch(Throwable ignore) {}

        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void getWeather(String woeid, String unit, RequestQueue rq, final WeatherClientListener listener) {
        String url2Call = makeWeatherURL(woeid, unit);
        Log.d("SwA", "Weather URL ["+url2Call+"]");
        final Weather result = new Weather();
        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2Call, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                parseResponse(s, result);
                listener.onWeatherResponse(result);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });

        rq.add(req);
    }

    private static Weather parseResponse (String resp, Weather result) {
        Log.d("SwA", "Response ["+resp+"]");
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(new StringReader(resp));

            String tagName = null;
            String currentTag = null;

            int event = parser.getEventType();
            boolean isFirstDayForecast = true;
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                tagName = parser.getName();

                if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (tagName.equals("yweather:wind")) {
                       // Log.d("SwA", "Tag [Wind]");
                        result.wind.chill = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "chill"));
                        result.wind.direction = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "direction"));
                        result.wind.speed  = (int) Float.parseFloat(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "speed"));
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("yweather:atmosphere")) {
                       // Log.d("SwA", "Tag [Atmos]");
                        result.atmosphere.humidity = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "humidity"));
                        result.atmosphere.visibility = Float.parseFloat(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "visibility"));
                        result.atmosphere.pressure = Float.parseFloat(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "pressure"));
                        result.atmosphere.rising = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rising"));
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("yweather:forecast")) {
                      //  Log.d("SwA", "Tag [Fore]");
                        if (isFirstDayForecast) {
                            result.forecast.code = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "code"));
                            result.forecast.tempMin = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "low"));
                            result.forecast.tempMax = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "high"));
                            isFirstDayForecast = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("yweather:condition")) {
                      //  Log.d("SwA", "Tag [Condition]");
                        result.condition.code = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "code"));
                        result.condition.description = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "text");
                        result.condition.temp = Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "temp"));
                        result.condition.date = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "date");
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("yweather:units")) {
                     //   Log.d("SwA", "Tag [units]");
                        result.units.temperature = "°" + parser.getAttributeValue(null, "temperature");
                        result.units.pressure = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "pressure");
                        result.units.distance = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "distance");
                        result.units.speed = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "speed");
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("yweather:location")) {
                        result.location.name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "city");
                        result.location.region = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "region");
                        result.location.country = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "country");
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("image"))
                        currentTag = "image";
                    else if (tagName.equals("url")) {
                        if (currentTag == null) {
                            result.imageUrl = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "src");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("lastBuildDate")) {
                       currentTag="update";
                    }
                    else if (tagName.equals("yweather:astronomy")) {
                        result.astronomy.sunRise = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "sunrise");
                        result.astronomy.sunSet = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "sunset");
                    }

                }
                else if (event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if ("image".equals(currentTag)) {
                       currentTag = null;
                    }
                }
                else if (event == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    if ("update".equals(currentTag))
                        result.lastUpdate = parser.getText();
                }
                event = parser.next();
            }

        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String makeQueryCityURL(String cityName) {
        // We remove spaces in cityName
        cityName = cityName.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        return YAHOO_GEO_URL + "/places.q(" + cityName + "%2A);count=" + Config.MAX_CITY_RESULT + "?appid=" + APPID;
    }

    private static String makeWeatherURL(String woeid, String unit) {
        return  YAHOO_WEATHER_URL + "?w=" + woeid + "&u=" + unit;
    }


    /* Pubblic listener interface */

    public static interface WeatherClientListener {
        public void onWeatherResponse(Weather weather);
    }
}
```

**My log file**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(14436): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

01 E/AndroidRuntime(14436): at com.ocs76584.cityinfo.Activity.WeatherActivity$2.onWeatherResponse(WeatherActivity.java:135)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at com.ocs76584.cityinfo.Provider.YahooClient$1.onResponse(YahooClient.java:106)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at com.ocs76584.cityinfo.Provider.YahooClient$1.onResponse(YahooClient.java:1)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
01-10 18:20:01.346: E/AndroidRuntime(14436):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: post your logcat and specify your line number 106 code

Comment: It might help if you told us what line 106 is!

Comment: listener.onWeatherResponse(result);

Comment: Check your `final WeatherClientListener listener` in your `getWeather()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Somewhere*, not in the code you've shown, you're calling `getWeather(String, String, RequestQueue, Listener)` with a `null` value for the `Listener`.